# Как к TabPanel прикрутить ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как к TabPanel прикрутить ScrollViewer?

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" 
                    Margin="-2,-2" 
                    Padding="10,0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}" 
                    TabStripPlacement="Left">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#171717"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ElementName=CreateAlbum, Path=ActualWidth}"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="70">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" 
                               Width="60" Margin="10">
                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   FontSize="15"
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В каком смысле «прикрутить»? Какого эффекта вы хотите добиться?

Comment: @VladD, добавил gif-ку как сейчас ведет себя таб панель. При уменьшении окна или когда таб итемов будет слишком много  должна появиться возможность прокрутки.

Comment: А если в каждый `TabItem` поместить `ListBox` и потом туда уже помещать элементы?